# Google Cloud Platform: VM Monitoring agent installation failing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-ops-agent

I tried installing the monitoring agent multiple times using both Google Cloud Console & Command Line. None of the approach worked.

**My OS Version:**

Description: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Release: 11

Codename: bullseye

**Installation Logs:**

```
curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/add-monitoring-agent-repo.sh
sudo bash add-monitoring-agent-repo.sh --also-install
```

Error:

> **Err:10 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-monitoring-bullseye-all Release
> 404 Not Found [IP: 142.250.182.206 443]**

Answer (score 1):

It fails because it's getting 404 from the legacy monitoring agent source list and you need the [updated Cloud Ops Agent script](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/ops-agent/installation):

```
curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh
```

You would also need to remove the apt source of google-cloud-monitoring:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-monitoring.list
```

Then run the script installation inside the VM Instance:

```
sudo bash add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh --also-install
```

As the [Legacy Monitoring Agent](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/monitoring#linux_operating_systems) does not support the Debian 11 Bullseye.